# Removing labels in Google Apps Account

Tags: c#

I wanted to ask that how do I remove the labels which are present in google apps account at one stroke.Now I can remove the labels but i need to do it one by one.How can i remove all the labels at one stroke.Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include details on why this is related to c#.

Comment: I guess you could write a web-scrapper utility in C# to automate the process, though I think if this isn't a common issue, manually doing it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of the page there is a More link under your labels. Inside that is a Manage Labels. This will let you delete labels from all emails at once.